# calculate mean of period in lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate, period

How to calculate mean of `period` in `lubridate` ?

```
library(lubridate)

# tibble
tbl <- tibble(time_1 = ymd_hms(c("2021-01-01 12:00:00"), ("2021-01-01 12:12:36"), ("2021-01-01 14:25:45")),
              time_2 = ymd_hms(c("2021-01-01 12:12:36"), ("2021-01-01 14:25:45"), ("2021-01-01 15:35:45")),
              time_period = seconds_to_period(difftime(time_2, time_1, units = 'sec')))

# calculate mean of period (WRONG ANSWER)
tbl %>% summarise(mean_val = mean(time_period))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The period object doesn't seem to work well with `mean`. You could use

```r
tbl %>%
  summarise(mean = seconds_to_period(mean(period_to_seconds(time_period))))
```

to get

```r
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  mean      
  <Period>  
1 1H 11M 55S
```

To get another representation, you could try

```r
tbl %>%
  summarise(
    mean = seconds_to_period(mean(period_to_seconds(time_period))),
    mean_val = mean(period_to_seconds(time_period)),
    days     = mean_val %/% (60*60*24),
    hours    = mean_val %/% (60*60),
    minutes  = mean_val %/% 60 %% 60 + round((mean_val %% 60)/60),
    value    = paste0(days, "d ", hours, "H ", minutes, "M")
    )
```

to get

```r
# A tibble: 1 x 6
  mean       mean_val  days hours minutes value    
  <Period>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>    
1 1H 11M 55S     4315     0     1      12 0d 1H 12M
```

I'm pretty sure, `lubridate` offers better tools for formating a `Period` object but I don't have much experience here.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Gal, is it possible to round off and remove the seconds i.e. `1H 12M` not  `1H 11M 55S`

Comment: Do you want it just displayed as `1H 12M` (as a string) or do you need a `Period` object you can work with?

Comment: Preferably `period` but string will also work

Comment: Edited the anwer.